# Remote App Won't Run for Accounts Other than Domain Admin

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

Environment

Server 2012 Standard
Attempting to access the server through RemoteApp from Windows 8.0

I have a 2012 Server I have published a RemoteApp from. This remote app runs a shortcut to a shared app on another machine. It is using the full path `\\asdfsadf\c$\ad\etc.` and is not dependent on a shared drive. I can run the RemoteApp fine from a Domain Admin login, but when attempting to run it as another user who is not a domain admin I get the following error :

The program did not start on the remote computer.

I am trying to determine how to make this application work from RemoteApp for all users. If I log onto the server and obtain a full desktop environment the app runs fine. Log off and attempt remote app and it fails.

Answer (score 3):

> "\asdfsadf\c$\ad\etc"

Your path references an admin share (`c$`), which isn't accessible by non-admin users.

Share the app's folder, set appropriate permissions on the share, and then use the direct path to the share (ie: `\\asdfsadf\sharedAppFolder`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, found it was permissions on the remoteapp's application folder. I diagnosed by using a tool called OpenedFilesView - to see what files the working user was "hitting", then checking permissions to ensure the non-working user was setup the same way.